# Enable file sharing amongst ubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu ?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, permissions, lubuntu, samba

I will try to explain the scenario in a least complicated manner;

I have 20 computers in here,

14 – Xubuntu (pc1, pc 2, pc 3, pc 4, pc 5, pc 6, pc 7, pc 8, pc 9, pc 10 pc,11, pc 12, pc13, pc14)
5 – Lubuntu (pc15, pc16, pc17, pc18, pc19)
1 – Ubuntu (pc20)

All connected to the LAN (Local Area Network)

Now, is it possible to enable pure file sharing among all of these ?

EVERY computer will have a folder named ‘shared’ on their desktop which should be able to get written and read by anyone on the LAN.

There should be NO username and password or any kind of authentication while copying/pasting or accessing the Shared folder (I don’t care about the security)

Please can someone help me in a way to set this thing up ?

And please consider that I can’t afford any fancy surprises because the end users (operators) are used to winXP file sharing.

Until now I’ve tried using Samba and sometimes it works sometimes it says permission denied, connection refused, volume not mounted. I’ve installed thunar file manager on every computer.

Sometimes while copying just a 2 MB file it takes ages, it keeps on saying copying….till my wit ends. And then I end up using a flash drive

Comment: Isnt this the same as this question and answer? http://askubuntu.com/questions/100790/how-to-enable-file-sharing-between-two-pcs?rq=1

Comment: http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-configure-samba-using-a-graphical-interface-in-ubuntu/ this might help you set up samba much simpler. is each computer sharing a folder that is stored locally on that computer, or is their one computer with the folder that you want to access on every other computer?

Answer (score 0):

Do it the traditional way. Share via Samba. Access via mounts. Bookmark them in your filemanager with windownames e.g C,D,E..etc.
For each PC install

```
samba
system-config-samba
```

From LxPanel menu, open System Tools > Samba 

share the folder as name 'C' and set to share to everyone.

Copy a startup script to every PC, and auto-execute at logon e.g

```
    sudo mkdir /mnt/C 2>/dev/null
    sudo umount /mnt/C 2>/dev/null
    sudo mkdir /mnt/D 2>/dev/null
    sudo umount /mnt/D 2>/dev/null
..etc..
    IPADR1=$(nmblookup -R host1 | grep 'host1' | cut -d' ' -f1)
    sudo mount --type cifs -o guest //$IPADR1/C /mnt/C -o uid=user1 -o gid=user1
    IPADR2=$(nmblookup -R host2 | grep 'host2' | cut -d' ' -f1)
    sudo mount --type cifs -o guest //$IPADR1/D /mnt/D -o uid=user2 -o gid=user2
..etc..
```

open /mnt/C in filemanager and bookmark it as 'C'.  .etc..

(http://petepr.hubpages.com/hub/Lubuntu-Linux-Network-File-Shares)